# How to use the hits addon in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I purchased the *hits addon* from http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/count-hits-tags/, but it is not showing any data in the admin panel.

The plugin is installed successfully and I have applied it in this way:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data" cache="yes" refresh="1" track_views="one" dynamic="no" status="open|featured"}

    {exp:hits:count_hits}          

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the link you provided, the instructions state:

> IMPORTANT: You MUST use one of the above parameters.

So change your tag to this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|pagination|member_data" cache="yes" refresh="1" track_views="one" dynamic="no" status="open|featured"}

    {exp:hits:count_hits entry_id="{entry_id}"}          

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Should begin to track hits.

Comment: hits not showing chart as showing in its addon documentation.